# How do I focus an image from the bottom left?

Tags: html, css, image, focus

I got everything pretty much figured out but I can't seem to override the margin-top. I need the 4th child to focus from the bottom not from the middle.

```
.gallerya a:focus img{
width: 350%; 
height: 350%;
margin-left:-120%;
margin-top:-50%;
position: absolute;
opacity: 1; 
z-index: 1; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #4D4D4D;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #4D4D4D;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #4D4D4D; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
-moz-transition-property: width, height;
-moz-transition-duration: 1s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
-o-transition-property:width, height;
-o-transition-duration: 1s;
-o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
cursor: default;
}

.gallerya a:first-child img{
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
}

.gallerya a:nth-child(3) img{
right:0;
margin-top: 0;
}

.gallerya a:nth-child(4) img{
margin-left:0;
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/alexdj1983/pen/NPZMre)

Comment: you mean remove the gap between the forth element and top of the page?

Comment: no, the img focuses from the top left corner by default,  margin-left:-120%;
margin-top:-50%; in a:focus img makes the img focus from the center (i need this for center img); right:0; margin-top: 0; overrides the margin-left and margin-top; but I can't figure out how to make the 4th img to focus from the bottom left (i got the left part down, but not the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean the bottom is fixed like this?

```
margin-top:auto; // reset
margin-left:0px!important;
bottom:0px!important;
```

Comment: yes, perfect, thank you! i was trying the bottom:0; and bottom:0%; but not bottom:0px;. Still got ways to go in learning CSS

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. If you mean you want to reset the margin-top:-50% and use a bottom/left position for this image you can simply try

```
margin-top:auto; // reset
margin-left:0px!important;
margin-bottom:0px!important;
```

Comment: i just want the 4th image to focus from the bottom left corner, instead of top left corner, adding 
  margin-top:auto;  
  margin-left:0px !important;
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
to .gallerya a:nth-child(4) img did not work

Comment: Oups ! typo mistake :(